# How to Categorise Images in GridView to make Custom Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-gridview

I have made few *Gallery modules by using GridView* i have used this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/,

but now this time i want to make it more custom for my usage, i **want to Categories Images**, Please see below Screen Shot

I *will be use static images under specific Categories*

How to make this kind of Image Gallery:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never tried, but i have found this sample code, and please try to custom it as you like:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/infinite-scrolling-gallery/

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by implementing Jeff Shrkey's SeperatedListadapter

http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

and you can

[Look 1](http://androidexam.blogspot.com/2011/09/listview-sectioned-headers-in-android.html)
[Look 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522454/android-separatedlistadapter-how-to-get-accurate-item-position-on-onclick)

> There isn’t an easy way of creating these separated lists, so I’ve put
>   together SeparatedListAdapter which does it quickly. To summarize,
>   we’re creating a new BaseAdapter that can contain several other
>   Adapters, each with their own section headers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Layout having a TextView and custom ListView. in each listItem have a GridView. and Load GridItems.

The TextView is for the Category Name.

Basically you must combine, the Custom ListView Implementation and GridView Implementation to achieve your objective. You can find Separate Tutorials for doing the same in the same androidhive website. But, you must work on combining them into one.

Comment: i agree with you great method step by step, but i never worked on this kind of module, so could you show me any sample code

Comment: I don't have any sample code. I have to implement that. I would need some time for that. just follow the tutorials, you can do it yourself its not that tough.

Comment: please implement this great functionality,bcoz i have tried several times but facing many kind of problems...for now thanks, and whenever you make that please inform me

Comment: sure buddy i will wait ...i appreciate your support

Comment: @SuriAmit : It turns out we can't use a view with scrollable items inside another scrollable view. I did complete the technique which i asked you to follow, and it did display as you wanted. But the gridview in each list item was not scrollable. So, what you could do is on click of a listitem(consisting of a TextView and Partial display of the GridView) display category name and complete gridView in separate activity(screen). I know this is not what you wanted. So i will be deleting this answer. just let me know when u see this reply. if you need the work which i have done let me know.

Comment: again thanks for support but not that i am looking to, please browse this link, i have found this very helpful, now i am going to make it custom for me, if possible you too start to make it custom as i need:http://blog.blundell-apps.com/infinite-scrolling-gallery/