# Separated list adapter - get the position of the item

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I have a SeperatedListAdapter with 2 sections and each section having 6 items in it.

Code:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(listViewListener);
```

Adding section headers and items in this fashion:

```
adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);
adapter.addSection(entry.getKey(), new ItemAdapter(this, 0, topics.toArray(array)));

OnItemClickListener listViewListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long duration) {
          Employee emp = emps.get(position - 1); 
    }
};
```

I have ArrayList as:

```
items from section 1
    Anand - 0
    Sunil - 1
    Suresh - 2
    Dev - 3
    Faran - 4
    Khan - 5
items from section 2
    Samba - 6
    Surendra - 7
    Rajesh - 9
    Rakesh - 10
    Satish - 11
```

Now in `OnItemClickListener` when I get the position, it's also taking the section header as position.

So I did it as `Employee emp = emps.get(position - 1);` but  up to 6 items (0-5 from my arraylist) is fine but after that the position is not proper. How can I solve this issue?

I need to pass the postion to my Arrray list in this fashion

```
Employee emp = emps.get(position - 1);
```

since I will be passing the employee object to another class.

see this too:

[Android - SeparatedListAdapter - How to get accurate item position on onClick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522454/android-separatedlistadapter-how-to-get-accurate-item-position-on-onclick)

Comment: did you used the settag way?

Comment: @PankajKumar No i havent used it

Comment: Ok can you share the code for adapter and the code how you set adpaters for sections?

Comment: @PankajKumar its here http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

Comment: Answer added. You only need to use `Employee emp = (Employee) adapter.getItem(position);`  to get correct item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mensiond in you comment you are using the [Separating Lists with Headers in Android 0.9](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) example.

So there is a method into adpater,

```
public Object getItem(int position) {  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return section;  
            if(position < size) return adapter.getItem(position - 1);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
        }  
        return null;  
    }
```

which returns the correct item.

So you only need to call this method, into `OnItemClickListener` like

```
OnItemClickListener listViewListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long duration) {
            Employee emp = (Employee) adapter.getItem(position); // HERE is the code to get correct item.
}
};
```

---

Add below method to `SeparatedListAdapter`

```
public Employee getItem(int position, ArrayList<Employee> lists) {  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return lists.get(position);   
            if(position < size) return lists.get(position - 1);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
        }  
        return null;  
    }
```

and call it as

```
Employee emp = adapter.getItem(position, emps);
```

Comment: yes i had tried that it says String cannot cast to my Employee

Comment: Yes thats correct. If you are giving String array to the adapter then the given method return the object which will be typecast-able to String not Employee. to get employee object you need to pass Employee array to Adapter.

Comment: this is how i am setting the section and the items adapter.addSection(entry.getKey(), new ItemAdapter(this, 0, topics.toArray(array)));

Comment: What is the type of `topics.toArray(array))`? String or Employee array? If Employee, then you should modify getItem of `ItemAdapter` adapter. If not there add this method into the class.

Comment: Its a string ArrayList<String> topics = entry.getValue();

Comment: Then you can not get Employee object from the method. Are you able to access `emps` list into SeparatedListAdapter?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38591/discussion-between-goofy-and-pankaj-kumar)

Comment: Buddy i have one more problem after solving this issue , can you please help me out

Comment: dude if you are free can you please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264300/bitmap-with-tile-mode-repeat-and-round-corners

Comment: thats ok, i have solved it, i have answered my own questions so that it will help some one in future.Just have a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264300/bitmap-with-tile-mode-repeat-and-round-corners/19268915#19268915